# Problems installing Diazo/plone.app.theming changes to buildout.cfg

Tags: osx-lion, plone, buildout, diazo

I am trying to install plone.app.theming using the following installation instructions:
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.theming#installation

My buildout.cfg is slightly different than the the "existing" information shown in these instructions. I have Plone 4.1.3 installed on a MacBook Pro running OS X Lion (10.7).

I am trying to find clear instructions for this installation. Please help! Thx

Answer (score 2):

In your buildout.cfg, in the variable extends add this line :

```
http://good-py.appspot.com/release/plone.app.theming/1.0b9
```

In the eggs variable, add this line :

```
plone.app.theming
```

That's it, rebuilt your buildout :

```
./bin/buildout
```